# アプリのバージョン番号は連番ではなくても良いのでしょうか？

Tags: ios

以前、App Storeにアプリをバージョン番号及びBuild番号を1.0.0でアップしました。
その後、バグが見つかったので1.0.1で申請をしたのですが、すぐに違うバグを見つけてしまったので、一度申請を取り下げて再度申請をあげることにしました。

調べたところ、再申請にはBuild番号を一つあげて1.0.2にする必要があるようですが、バージョン番号も1.0.2にすると、Storeに表示されるアプリは1.0.1がない事になります。

こう言った風に、バージョン番号が過去のものと連番ではなくなってしまうような申請は、リジェクトになってしまったりしないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己回答です。
最終的に以下のように対応し、無事に審査が通りました。

バージョン番号：1.0.1
ビルド番号：1.0.1.1

つまり

- 申請毎にビルド番号は必ずあげる必要がある
- バージョン番号はリジェクト時と同じでも良い
- 3桁以上でも問題ない（数値が上がってさえいれば良い）

1.0.1.1の形にすれば
次回もし1.0.2にする場合、build番号も1.0.2に出来るのでトラブルが少なそうです。

Answer (score 1):

取り下げて再アップする時にバージョン番号を上げないといけないのは、
Apple側の仕様変更なので問題ないです。

[【アプリ申請】iTunes Connectが新しくなった！！　申請取り下げバイナリの再アップする方法](http://bribser.co.jp/blog/new-itunes-connect/)
※ページ中ほどの「バイナリの再アップ」に下記記述があります。

> バイナリを再アップするには、ビルドバージョンを上げるしかないようです。
>   以前は、バイナリのビルドバージョンをアップしなくても再アップ出来たと思うのですが・・・。

念のための補足として、以前同じ状況で問題なく申請を通過した実績もあります。
申請
　↓
取り下げ
　↓
バージョンアップして再申請

Answer (score 0):

アプリの最初のリリースが1.0.0でなくてもリジェクトはされないと思います。
また、次のリリースの番号が飛んでいてもリジェクトはされないと思います。
ビルド番号がリリースのたびに大きくなっていれば良いだけなのではないでしょうか。
(私の場合は大丈夫でした)

Info.plistなどで表示バージョンとビルド番号は別々に設定できるので、それをうまく設定するという手もあると思います。